# Safety of using and approach to "floating" promises

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

In the [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) it explains,

> Important: Always return results, otherwise callbacks won't catch the result of a previous promise (with arrow functions, () => x is short for () => { return x; }). If the previous handler started a promise but did not return it, there's no way to track its settlement anymore, and the promise is said to be "floating".

With this little json file:

```
{
  "ingredients": "flour,sugar,butter,chocolate"
}
```

```
const listOfIngredients = [];
console.clear();
function doSomething() {
  fetch('http://127.0.0.1:4000/test.json')
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((data) => {
    data.ingredients.split(',').forEach(i => listOfIngredients.push(i)); 
  // doesn't return
  })
  .then((nothing) => {
    console.log(nothing); // undefined, of course
    console.log(listOfIngredients);
    return "and coconut";
  })
  .then((something) => {
    listOfIngredients.push(something);
    console.log(listOfIngredients);
  });
}
doSomething();
```

Result:

```
undefined
['flour', 'sugar', 'butter', 'chocolate']
['flour', 'sugar', 'butter', 'chocolate', 'and coconut']
```

So, I *think* that the result of the success callback, `(data) => {...}` is (said to be) "floating", but that since in this case, the promise returns immediately, the chained `(nothing) => {...}` and `(something) => {...}` callbacks succeed.

If I update the `(nothing)` callback to contain another fetch, that fetch *does* need to be returned (`(nothing) => { return fetch...`  otherwise we get `['flour', 'sugar', 'butter', 'chocolate', undefined]`. Makes sense.

So, in promise chains, do you *only* need to return from the callbacks for promise objects that handle asynchronous operations?

Comment: If you are not doing something asynchronous why would you be using another then? Code smell.

Comment: Great question. @epascarello. This example is basically from the MDN docs, linked above. (in the first `// OR` example) on the page.

Comment: Really, you want all data that depends on async stuff to flow down out of promises so that you don't accidentally try to use it when it isn't actually populated.  You gate off the data through `.then()`.  `listOfIngredients` is dangerous because if you access it outside of this context it may or may not be populated.  That leads to very very frustrating bugs.

Comment: You return from callbacks when the next handler expects data. It doesn't have anything to do with asynchronicity, although as noted, using a promise chain as a way to break up synchronous operations is a bit sus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, in promise chains, do you only need to return from the callbacks for promise objects that handle asynchronous operations?

You are correct. From the mdn doc you provided:

> If the previous handler started a promise but did not return it, there's no way to track its settlement anymore, and the promise is said to be "floating".

Notice in this one:

```js
.then((data) => {
    data.ingredients.split(',').forEach(i => listOfIngredients.push(i)); 
  // doesn't return
  })
```

you aren't starting a promise so there is no issue.

Floating promises have nothing to do with returning the data but rather returning when the promise resolves you could do something like this for instance:

```js
.then(async res => {
    window.myGlobal = await res.json();
}).then(nothing => /* ... continue */ undefined);
```

even though we aren't returning the data directly the function provided only resolves when `res.json()` has finished so we don't have any hanging promises.

Incidentally your example does have a hanging promise: the `doSomething` function. the `doSomething` function should be returning the `fetch` call as in:

```js
function doSomething() {
  return fetch('http://127.0.0.1:4000/test.json')
  /* ... */
}
```

Note that if you didn't want to return the fetch for some reason you could still avoid the hanging promise by using `async/await` like:

```js
async function doSomething() {
  await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:4000/test.json')
  /* ... */
}
```

this is functionally equivalent to the following however:

```js
function doSomething() {
  return fetch('http://127.0.0.1:4000/test.json')
      /* ... your existing .then chain goes here */
      .then(() => undefined)
  }
}
```

Also note that as mentioned in the comments you are probably doing something really bad if you are writing code this way (not returning the results of asyncronous operations but still wanting to do things after they complete)

Comment: What do you mean by 'you aren't starting a promise so there is no issue'. Aren't you always starting a promise when you use `then()`?

Comment: @MikeiLL you aren't starting a promise inside of `.then`. You didn't call `fetch` or any other asynchronous functions inside of the callback. the `.then` will return immediately if it doesn't return a promise

Comment: oh! So `then()` _might_ return a promise object, but doesn't necessarily.  Am I understanding that correctly?

Comment: Yes exactly. If then doesn't return a promise then it is a pass through

Comment: Sorry, no I read that wrong. What I meant is the callback to then might return a promise object, but doesn't necessarily

Comment: Basically if you create a promise inside of the `.then` function you need to return it or await it (which is sugar for returning the promise.then(undefined)). If you don't create a promise inside of the callback to .then it will basically just make a new promise with the value you returned. So yes a new promise is being created but that promise is created from .then this is why you have to return from `doSomething` this has nothing to do with whether you return inside of the callback to `.then` sorry I'm making this so confusing

Comment: I think it just _is_ complex. Thanks a lot for the great input, man.